# qooxdoo new property not visible in log tool

Tags: properties, qooxdoo

I am checking an instance of a qooxdoo class using console.log('%o', inst).
Here the properties are shown with leading "$$user..." marks.
But when adding a new property to the class, it is not shown in the console.log-output.
The code is running using the new property; so the syntax and class structure is ok. I checked in release and debug mode.
What do I have to do to see the new property also in the console.log output ?
Or is there something cached so it will not be shown until a certain refresh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qooxdoo uses `$$user_` to store the current, user provided, property value. The `$$user_` values are only set if the property has been actively set after the object properties are constructed during class initialization.

Having some kind of *init* value is not enough, so you've to put something in there actively to make them visible in the `console.log` call above.

The init values are stored in the prototype as `$$init_` followed by the variable name. So

```
qx.Class.define("foobar", {
  extend: qx.core.Object,

  properties: {
    test1 : {},
    test2 : {init: 5}
  }
});
```

will result in no single `$$user_test1` or `$$user_test2` directly after you initialized the class. If you call `setTest2(99)`, you'll see that `$$user_test2` shows up in the console - and it disappears if you call `resetTest2()`.

To answer the question: you can only enforce having `$$user_` values to be set, by putting someting in actively. Or better define a *watch* in your chrome console that calls `getTest2()` on the watched object.